# Fossil add for external directory

Tags: fossil

I have read some of the questions and answers here, but it none match my situation exactly.

I want to keep all my fossil repos in a single place.

so I have

c:\Fossil_Repos\ with a repo for WebPages_Repo and another for Dev_repo etc etc etc

I would like to keep my original web pages and development pages in separated directories that are oustide of the Fossil_Repos directory, here is my structure

```
c:\Fossile_Repos\
c:\DevEnvironment\
c:\WebPageDevelopment\
```

This structure seems not to be unreasonable.

If from within my c:\Fossile_Repos\ I run the commands

```
fossil open Dev_Repo
fossil add c:\DevEnvironment
```

Then I see a listing of all the directories and files underneath c:\DevEnvironment, however I then go on to add

```
fossil commit -m "first deposit"
```

And get an error message on the first file saying the file doesn't exist. Note that the file path is correct (however it report the direcory as C:/DevEnvironment/firstFile.xml using the unix method of file separators)

Anyone got any thoughts on if I can do this or not?

thanks in advance

David

Comment: Just a thought in case anyone is interested. I've got multiple repos because I'm migrating from an ANT solution to a Maven solution (I've converted my ANT project structure to better reflect the locatin of source code etc in a Maven pattern) . If Anyone can see a solution for easily sharing just the java source code files that may be really cool too, I'll create another question if required, then I can give the solution its required acceptance too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can keep the repos wherever you like.  However, you must issue the commands to fossil from inside the checkout.

So, in your example:

```
cd c:\DevEnvironment
fossil open c:\Fossile_Repos\repo_file_name
.. edit the files ...
fossil commit -m "first deposit"
```

Comment: Ah Cool, I never though about openin the repo from a different location... I'll mark yours the solution... although its taking a long time.... coffee time I think.